# Crawler over unstructured html with nodejs

Tags: node.js, xpath, web-crawler, cheerio

I need to crawl/scrap an static unstructured HTML, I'm trying to get the content with a nodejs code, I tried with cheerio and xpath unsuccessfully.

http://static.puertos.es/pred_simplificada/Predolas/Tablas/Cnt/PAS.html

The Xpath of the first element to get is /html/body/center/center/table/tbody/tr[3] and then I need to get every TD text in the TR.

If try to get the tbody node

```
      var parser = new parse5.Parser();
      var document = parser.parse(response.toString());
      var xhtml = xmlser.serializeToString(document);
      var doc = new dom().parseFromString(xhtml);
      var select = xpath.useNamespaces({"x": "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"});
      var nodes = select("//x:tbody", doc);
```

I always receive a `[]` nodes.

With cheerio I try to iterate the TR elements but as I mentioned above unsuccessfully.

```
var $ = cheerio.load(response);
$('tr').each(function(i, e) {
    console.log("Content %j", $(e));
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seams that cheerio is not working properly with unstructured and without CSS HTML. So, I tried with another workaround using YQL following [that tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/screen-scraping-with-nodejs--net-25560)

```
select * from html where url='http://static.puertos.es/pred_simplificada/Predolas/Tablas/Cnt/PAS.html' and xpath='//html/body/center/center/table/tbody'
```

With yql I'm getting exactly what I needed, So I will integrate it [node-yql](https://github.com/derek/node-yql)

Answer (score 0):

Use option **all lowercase tags** because HTML may contain mixed `tr` and `TR`:

```
 $ = cheerio.load(html, { lowerCaseTags: true });
```

You should do the same for attributes as well:

```
 $ = cheerio.load(html, { lowerCaseTags: true, lowerCaseAttributeNames : true });
```

Hope that helps.